Split and differentiable locally trivial submersion, and more confusions on a proof in John H Hubbard's book
The "split" means

Let E, F be Banach spaces, A surjective linear map $f:E\rightarrow F$ is said to  split if $ker f$ admits a closed complement. More generally, a submersion is a split submersion  if its derivative split at every point.

In Chapter 6 section 2, Page 241 of John H. Hubbard's book "Teichmüller theory and Applications to Topology, Geometry and Dynamics",  he wanted to prove that "proper submersions always admits a locally horizontally analytic trivializations".

Proposition 6.2.3  A proper analytic submersion $p: X\rightarrow T$ of Banach analytic manifolds always locally admits horizontally analytic trivializations

Here is the definition we needed:

Definition 6.2.1 An analytic submersion $p: X\rightarrow T$ admits a horizontally analytic trivializations by a manifold S if there exists a homeomorphism $\phi: S\times T\rightarrow X$ commuting with projections to T such that for every $s\in S$, the map $t\rightarrow \phi(s,t)$ is analytic;
An analytic submersion $p: X\rightarrow T$ locally admits a horizontally analytic trivializations if every $t\in T$ has a neighborhood U such that $p: p^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ admits a horizontally analytic trivializations by $X_{t}$

My questions arise in his abstract proof. To make my questions self-contained I will copy the proof totally here.

Proof: Set $X_{t}:=p^{-1}(t)$ for all $t\in T$. Choose $t_{0}\in T$ and set $X_{0}:=X_{t_{0}}$. Choose an integral $k>0$, and consider the space $C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)$ composed of pairs  $(t,f)$ with $t\in T$ and $f: X_{0}\rightarrow X_{t}$ a $C^{k}$ map. Then $C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)$ naturally has the structure of a complex analytic submanifold of the manifold $C^{k}(X_{0},X)$ such that the natural projection $$P:C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)\rightarrow T$$ is an analytic submersion, see Appendix A5. It isn't absolutely clear that this submersion splits, but the derivative
$$[DP(t,f)]:T_{(t,f)}C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)\rightarrow T_{t}T$$ does split as a real-linear map, since the family $p: X\rightarrow T$ differentially local trivial. Now the following lemma, together with the implicit function theorem, finishes the proof.
Lemma 6.2.4 Let E and F be complex Banach spaces, $u:E\rightarrow F$ a $\mathbb{C}$-linear surjective map, and $v:F\rightarrow E$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map such that $u\circ v=id$, then there exists $w:F\rightarrow E$ is an $\mathbb{C}$-linear map such that $u\circ w=id$

I believe that throughout the Appendix 5 of his book, he wanted to use the following theorem that seems to be the most related:

Proposition A5.13 Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a split submersion.Then the space of $C_{Y}^{k}(M,X)$ of $C^{k}$-mappings $f:M\rightarrow X$ such that $p\circ f$ is constant is a Banach analytic sub manifold of $C^{k}(M,X)$, and p induces a split submersion $(p_{*})_{Y}: C_{Y}^{k}(M,X)\rightarrow Y$

I have the following questions,

As in the bold part of the proof, why the derivative
$$[DP(t,f)]:T_{(t,f)}C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)\rightarrow T_{t}T$$ does split as a real-linear map? It seems that $C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)$ may be not of a finite dimension. I know that the family $p: X\rightarrow T$ is differentially local trivial by Ehresmann Theorem. Then what's the relationship between split and differentially locally trivial?

What's the relationship between the Lemma 6.2.4 and the fact that a map is split?

Even though the $[DP(t,f)]:T_{(t,f)}C_{T}^{k}(X_{0},X)\rightarrow T_{t}T$ does split as a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map by the lemma, how to use implicit function theorem to prove the original statement?


